# Itextsharp remove page numberer

Tags: itext

I've spent much time to no avail on this issue. My PDF pages are automatically numbered '*Page 1 of 0*' when creating a PDF as follows:

```
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 25, 25))
            using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms))
            {
                writer.PageEvent = new TextEvents();
                document.Open();
                document.NewPage();
                document.Add(new Phrase("Hello World!"));
                document.Close();
                writer.Close();

                var docout = ms.ToArray();

                ms.Close();

                return docout;
            }
```

How do I stop this behaviour? I do not want a page numberer.

Comment: You don't show the part of your code where page numbering is implemented. Hint: look for a page event listener set to the PdfWriter, or for a second pass using a PdfStamper to stamp the page numbers.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've updated the code. I don't implement page numbering which is was confuses me?

Comment: Apparently you do, because iText doesn't add page numbers unless you tell it to add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
writer.PageEvent = new TextEvents();
```

you tell itext to send page events to an instance of your own `TextEvents` class. As no other part of the code you show adds page numbers, it must be this class of yours that does.

You can test this by removing the code line quoted above.

Beware: probably that `TextEvents` class does something else, too, probably something you want. Instead of completely removing that line above, therefore, you might eventually have to analyse your `TextEvents` class and only remove the unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above answer, `TextEvents()` should be extending `PdfPageEventHelper` which has an `onEndPage()` method where you will find the code that adds page x of n.